# Measuring Clock Cycles C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to benchmark a series of algorithms by using the C# StopWatch function, using:

```
var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// Do something
timer.Stop();
var elapsed2 = timer.ElapsedTicks;
Console.WriteLine(elapsed2);
```

My question is what these ticks actually relate to. I.e. are these clock cycles. I know I can get the Frequency from `Stopwatch.Frequency`, but is this actually the same as clock cycles. I.e. a tick count of 553534 corresponds to as many CPU cycles.

Comment: You know, [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks.aspx) answers a lot of questions.

Comment: Yeah documentation is good. And whats is funny...many questions which is asked and the answer is in documentation usually is marked as NOTE.

Comment: Clock cycles wouldn't have much meaning anyway.  Multi-level memory caches, pipelined execution, interrupts, ... all conspire to make exact measurement of CPU cycles quite a challenge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Note
> Stopwatch ticks are different from DateTime.Ticks. Each tick in the DateTime.Ticks value represents one 100-nanosecond interval. Each tick in the ElapsedTicks value represents the time interval equal to 1 second divided by the [Frequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency(v=vs.110).aspx).

Frequency:

> The timer frequency indicates the timer precision and resolution. For example, a timer frequency of 2 million ticks per second equals a timer resolution of 500 nanoseconds per tick. In other words, because one second equals 1 billion nanoseconds, a timer frequency of 2 million ticks per second is equivalent to 2 million ticks per 1 billion nanoseconds, which can be further simplified to 1 tick per 500 nanoseconds.
>
> The Frequency value depends on the resolution of the underlying timing mechanism. If the installed hardware and operating system support a high-resolution performance counter, then the Frequency value reflects the frequency of that counter. Otherwise, the Frequency value is based on the system timer frequency.
>
> Because the Stopwatch frequency depends on the installed hardware and operating system, the Frequency value remains constant while the system is running.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the capabilities of the system.

The [`IsHighResolution` field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can tell you how the `Stopwatch` class tells time. If it is `true`, then it uses the performance counter, and the ticks might be clock cycles. What they actually represent is dependent on the harware.